# Can I use constant parameters in overloaded struct operators?

Tags: c#, struct, operator-overloading, c#-7.2

I can define the following immutable struct in a  `.NET Core 2.0` class library:

```
public struct S {

    public readonly int v;

    public S(int value) => v = value;

    public static S operator +(in S l, in S r)
        => new S(l.v + r.v);

}
```

In a second project (a `.NET Core 2.0` console app), I'm attempting to use the overloaded operator. Therefore, I added a project reference to the library project. But the following code fails to compile:

```
class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args)
        => Console.WriteLine((new S(4) + new S(3)).v);

}
```

Error message:

> Error CS0019: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'S' and 'S'

Details:

- I've configured both projects to use the latest `C#` version (`C# 7.2`)
- using `.NET CORE 2.0` as target framework
- compilation works if I use it in the same project
- compilation works if I remove the `in` modifier for `l` and `r`
- using the `ref` modifier fo  `l` and `r` fails with `ERROR CS0631`
- my environment: VS 2017 15.5.5 Community

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a compiler bug that has been reported to the team in this issue: [Use in-parameter operator from different assembly](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/23689). It looks like the fix is in master, but I can confirm that the issue still exists in 15.5.6.